# How to get the latest value from the JSON document inside MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, join

The Mysql version is `8.0.18-commercial`
I have written the following query which displays results from `details` column

```
select details from table t1;

Output:
[
  {
    "Msg": "Job Running",
    "Task": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "Date": "2020-07-20 16:25:15",
  },
  {
    "Msg": "Job failed",
    "Task": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "Date": "2020-07-20 16:35:24",
  }
]
```

I want the `Msg` value only from the last element which has latest `Date`

My desired output is displaying `Msg` of the element with `latest date` :

```
ColumnName      ColumnValue
Msg             Job failed
```

I have written following query but it is giving `null` output

```
select details->>"$.Msg" from table t1;
```

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906435/convert-json-array-in-mysql-to-rows for how to convert a JSON array to rows. Then you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 to get the row with the latest value.

Comment: Do you want the message of the last array element, or of the element with latest date?

Comment: I want msg of the element with latest date

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you store this as JSON? It would have been easier if you had stored this in a normal manner, with each array member on a row, and each object field in a normal column. In most cases, using JSON for structure data like this makes it _harder_ to query data in an SQL database.

Comment: I am migrating data from mongo collection and it can be migrated in the form of JSON documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQ. 8.0, you can use `json_table()` to unnest the json array to rows, then `row_number()` to keep the latest record per original row.

Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, you would phrase this as:

```
select msg, activity_date
from (
    select x.*, row_number() over(partition by t.id order by x.activity_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
    cross join json_table(
        t.details,
        '$[*]' columns(
            msg varchar(50) path '$.Msg',
            activity_date datetime path '$.activityDate'
        )
    ) x
) t
where rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2610c8bca44653a1e9090cf1342de0d4)**:

```
msg        | activity_date      
:--------- | :------------------
Job failed | 2020-07-20 16:35:24
```