# How to update multi rows in MySQL from Array JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have an JSON array that contains product table ids like: `[2, 4, 5, 14]`. How do I update the status of a Product to `0` if its ID is contained in the JSON array?

Here is the Product table:

| id | name | color | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Samsung S9 | White | 24000000 | 1 |
| 3 | Oppo F5 | Red | 7000000 | 1 |
| 4 | Macbook | Grey | 5000000 | 1 |
| 5 | MSI GT 900 | Black | 12000000 | 1 |
| 12 | Iphone 11 Pro Max | Green | 1800000 | 1 |
| 13 | Nokia 6300 | Blue | 1100000 | 1 |
| 14 | IPad Mini | White | 2000000 | 1 |

Comment: I can't make comment bc I am new, but think this could help.
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906435/convert-json-array-in-mysql-to-rows)

Comment: Join by JSON_CONTAINS or JSON_SEARCH. Or parse array with JSON_TABLE then join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_TABLE()` (in MySQL > 8.0, scroll down for MySQL <= 5.7 solution).

You need to use the appropriate JSON selector:

| **Selector** | **Description** |
| --- | --- |
| `$` | the current JSON document |
| `.key` | select value from the key |
| `[n]` | select element `n` from JSON array |
| `.*` | wildcard, all values of a JSON object, as an array |
| `[*]` | wildcard, all the values of a JSON array, as an array |
| `**` | wildcard, all paths that lead to a suffix |

So, if `@j = '[2, 4, 5, 14]'` is your JSON array, then the query

```
SELECT * 
   FROM JSON_TABLE(@j, 
                   "$[*]" 
                   COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$")
   ) data;
```

will get you the array contents as a table:

| Value |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 14 |

You can use this subquery in an `UPDATE` to check whether your respective `id` is in it:

```
UPDATE tab 
   SET status = 0
 WHERE id in (SELECT * 
                FROM JSON_TABLE(@j, "$[*]" COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$")) data
);
```

will get you the following:

| id | name | color | price | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Samsung S9 | White | 24000000 | 0 |
| 3 | Oppo F5 | Red | 7000000 | 1 |
| 4 | Macbook | Grey | 5000000 | 0 |
| 5 | MSI GT 900 | Black | 12000000 | 0 |
| 12 | Iphone 11 Pro Max | Green | 1800000 | 1 |
| 13 | Nokia 6300 | Blue | 1100000 | 1 |
| 14 | IPad Mini | White | 2000000 | 0 |

In case your JSON looks differently, you need to change the PATH in the `JSON_TABLE()` call accordingly. For example:

```
SET @k = '{"id": [2, 4, 5, 14] }'
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(@k, "$.id[*]" COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$")) data;
```

or

```
SET @l = '{"outer": [{"id": 2} , {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 14}] }'
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(@l, "$.outer[*]" COLUMNS(Value INT PATH "$.id")) data;
```

have the same result.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61e0c5733a2675fd0ac68133263bcff3).

---

For MySQL <= 5.7, `JSON_TABLE()` is not available, but you can achieve the same using `JSON_CONTAINS()`. Since `JSON_CONTAINS()` needs a JSON as argument, you need to `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` your `INTEGER` id to a `CHAR`:

```
UPDATE tab 
   SET status = 0
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(@j, CAST(id as CHAR(20)), '$');
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=85f0afb4a076fb188f13e1f6f22f465d).

Comment: I tried your way but my query can execute and  show error: 'You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column'. I tried with example MySQL <=5.7

Comment: It seems that MySQL does not recognize the use of the `id` in the `JSON_CONTAINS()`function as key column in the `WHERE` condition.  One way to get around this is to disable safe update mode before running your query by `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` and re-enable it afterwards with `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;`.  See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac19243a22f2ce7366d29c98d7ef9f1e).