# SQL query for below statement

Tags: mysql, json

Input
Both ID and Name column values are an array types.

```
 id name
 [1,2,3,4,5] [a,b,c,d]
```

Output

```
Id Name
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 null
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support array type columns

Comment: For MySQL, its JSON type

Comment: can try this answer for mysql 8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597424/3991211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unfold them with [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html).

> ```
> SELECT ids.Id, names.Name
> FROM test t
> CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.id,   '$[*]' COLUMNS(ordinal FOR ORDINALITY, Id INT PATH '$')) AS ids
> LEFT JOIN  JSON_TABLE(t.name, '$[*]' COLUMNS(ordinal FOR ORDINALITY, Name TEXT PATH '$')) AS names
>   ON names.ordinal = ids.ordinal;
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Name
> -: | :---
>  1 | a   
>  2 | b   
>  3 | c   
>  4 | d   
>  5 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=703c81fbd2f95e827b9880efb68045f6)*

Answer (score 0):

You can not do such thing directly from array. You must break them in parallel parts like you showed in the second diagram. Then you insert data one by by row.

Answer (score 0):

### PostgreSQL

Array Datatype

```
postgres=# create table arr(id int[],"name" char[]);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into arr values(array[1,2,3,4,5],array['a','b','c','d']);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from arr;
     id      |   name
-------------+-----------
 {1,2,3,4,5} | {a,b,c,d}
(1 row)

postgres=# select unnest(id) id ,unnest("name") "name"  from arr;
 id | name
----+------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
  4 | d
  5 |
(5 rows)
```

JSON Datatype

```
postgres=# create table arrj(id json, "name" json);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into arrj values(array_to_json('{1,2,3,4,5}'::int[]),array_to_json('{"a","b","c","d"}'::char[]));
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from arrj;
     id      |       name
-------------+-------------------
 [1,2,3,4,5] | ["a","b","c","d"]
(1 row)

postgres=# select json_array_elements_text(id) id ,json_array_elements_text(name) "name" from arrj;
 id | name
----+------
 1  | a
 2  | b
 3  | c
 4  | d
 5  |
(5 rows)
```