# Mysql - Extract json -multiply with one of the attribute

Tags: mysql, json, json-extract

I have json array like

```
[{"name":"MyName","age":10.0},{"name":"yourName","age":20.0}]
```

stored in MySql. Now the task is , I want to multiply by say 2 with all the age attribute, so the result json would be

```
[{"name":"MyName","age":20.0},{"name":"yourName","age":40.0}]
```

and update this newly generated json to some other column in the same record. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you mysql 8? then you could use JSON_TABLE

Comment: Hi @nbk, Thanks for reply. My sql version is 5.7 aurora

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @nbk, using `JSON_TABLE`.

```
update test_json tj
set json_2 = 
(
select json_arrayagg(json_object("name",name, "age",age)) 
from 
(
select t.id, p.name, p.age * 2 age
from test_json t, 
json_table(json_object("anytext",json_1),
'$.anytext[*]'
columns (
  name varchar(30) PATH '$.name',
  age int PATH '$.age' )
) p
) d
where d.id = tj.id
group by id
) ;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDTRoPqAXh4uoB2SMnDZYJ/0).

It is working in current form, but you might need to add additional conditions to update after set such as `where exists`.

Only the select part -

```
select id, json_arrayagg(json_object("name",name, "age",age)) orig_json,
json_arrayagg(json_object("name",name, "age",newage)) new_json
from 
(
select t.id, p.name, p.age age, p.age * 2 newage
from test_json t, 
json_table(json_object("anytext",json_1),
'$.anytext[*]'
columns (
  name varchar(30) PATH '$.name',
  age int PATH '$.age' )
) p
) d
group by id ;
```

updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDTRoPqAXh4uoB2SMnDZYJ/1).

Comment: Updated, you can check.

Comment: Also, possibly, if you can put details of why or what is not working in your case,

Comment: MySQL supports multiple-table update. The query which uses this syntax is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql 5,7 it grets a little more complicated. adapated from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153230/5193536

I  added all steps so you can undertsand the orocess, of extracting and agian jsonfy the the result.

The last select only shows the the result as text, so that you can see the changes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (rec_num INT, jdoc JSON);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES 
>   (1, '[{"name":"MyName","age":10.1},{"name":"yourName","age":20.0}]'), 
>   (2, '[{"name":"MyName2","age":10.0},{"name":"yourName2","age":20.0}]');
> ```

> ```
> SET @json = '[{"name":"MyName","age":10.0},{"name":"yourName","age":20.0}]'
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json,'$[0].name')
> ```

> ```
> | JSON_EXTRACT(@json,'$[0].name') |
> | :------------------------------ |
> | "MyName"                        |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   rec_num,
>   idx,
>   CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].name'))) as CHAR) AS name
>   ,CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].age'))) AS DECIMAL(3,1) ) * 2 AS age
> FROM t1
>   -- Inline table of sequential values to index into JSON array
> JOIN ( 
>   SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  2 AS idx UNION
>   -- ... continue as needed to max length of JSON array
>   SELECT  3
>   ) AS indexes
> WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')) IS NOT NULL
> ORDER BY rec_num, idx;
> ```
>
> ```
> rec_num | idx | name      |  age
> ------: | --: | :-------- | ---:
>       1 |   0 | MyName    | 20.2
>       1 |   1 | yourName  | 40.0
>       2 |   0 | MyName2   | 20.0
>       2 |   1 | yourName2 | 40.0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> rec_num,json_arrayagg(
>     json_merge(
>           json_object('name', name), 
>           json_object('age', age)
>     ) 
> ) jdoc FROM (
> SELECT
>   rec_num,
>   idx,
>   CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].name'))) as CHAR) AS name
>   ,CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].age'))) AS DECIMAL(3,1) ) * 2 AS age
> FROM t1
>   -- Inline table of sequential values to index into JSON array
> JOIN ( 
>   SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  2 AS idx UNION
>   -- ... continue as needed to max length of JSON array
>   SELECT  3
>   ) AS indexes
> WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')) IS NOT NULL
> ORDER BY rec_num, idx) t
> GROUP BY rec_num
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> rec_num | jdoc                                                                  
> ------: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------
>       1 | [{"age": 20.2, "name": "MyName"}, {"age": 40.0, "name": "yourName"}]  
>       2 | [{"age": 20.0, "name": "MyName2"}, {"age": 40.0, "name": "yourName2"}]
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE t1
> JOIN
> (SELECT 
> rec_num,json_arrayagg(
>     json_merge(
>           json_object('name', name), 
>           json_object('age', age)
>     ) 
> ) jdoc FROM (
> SELECT
>   rec_num,
>   idx,
>   CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].name'))) as CHAR) AS name
>   ,CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, '].age'))) AS DECIMAL(3,1) ) * 2 AS age
> FROM t1
>   -- Inline table of sequential values to index into JSON array
> JOIN ( 
>   SELECT  0 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  1 AS idx UNION
>   SELECT  2 AS idx UNION
>   -- ... continue as needed to max length of JSON array
>   SELECT  3
>   ) AS indexes
> WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, CONCAT('$[', idx, ']')) IS NOT NULL
> ORDER BY rec_num, idx) t
> GROUP BY rec_num) t2 USING(rec_num) 
> SET t1.jdoc = t2.jdoc
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT rec_num,CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(jdoc) as CHAR) FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> rec_num | CAST( JSON_UNQUOTE(jdoc) as CHAR)                                 
> ------: | :-----------------------------------------------------------------
>       1 | [{"age": 20.2, "name": "MyName"}, {"age": 40, "name": "yourName"}]
>       2 | [{"age": 20, "name": "MyName2"}, {"age": 40, "name": "yourName2"}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a87320bf73c938574d9eca425fa40a2d)*

Comment: Thanks @nbk for your detailed explanation. And here the size of JSON is unknown. So it has to union all to all the records. So how do you will do it?

Comment: increase the number of indexes to 50000, it really doesn't matter as only the existing will be fetched,

Comment: yes, as you don't know how many array elements there are. Bust would be mysql 8 as i mentioned, but i doubt that you will habe more than 300, but who knows.  A normalized table would make the world much simpler than json.

Comment: this is a new question, so accept and upvote existing answer if they helped and ask ask a new on that are the rules here. There are some JSON functions in Mysql 5.7 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html read up on them and try it your self, you with my code that upting is a complex problem, add some addiotional json not so much,but try it yourself and if that goes wrong ask a new question