# Count the duplicate values on multiple array and sort it to highest

Tags: mysql

I have a target where I have this DUPLICATE checker with COUNT for multiple arrays. As we can see. Any suggestions on how I make this work? Thank you and have a nice day.

**DATA:**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [5,6,8,4,2] |
| 2 | [2,3,4,1,8] |
| 3 | [9,3,2,1,10] |

**Normal result:**

| number | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

**This is my target result with sorting (Highest count):**

| number | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |

Comment: What is the _type_ of the `value` column?

Comment: Hello @TimBiegeleisen. Varchar 255. Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you stop storing your data this way.

Comment: Do you have any better approach? I'm willing to learn and apply it. Thank you @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: A dozen lines of PHP could do this. Do you need it all to be SQL?

Comment: Normal Result? Does that mean you have code which splits the arrays?

Comment: @SimonGoater Yes, if possible. Thank you

Comment: @P.Salmon Currently, I'm working on the SPLIT. But if you have any suggestion on how can I improve my target/codes, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597424/724039   and how to use it with this data: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/_nrQSu7L)

Comment: about "storing your data this way": [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Luuk Hello, thank you for these. I can easily do this https://prnt.sc/VD0IJOd_vpRW 

But i'm just worrying since it might reach millions in a future so rather than storing the number per row, i stored it as an array. 

Can you enlighten me regarding my question? Do you think it's okay even it reaches a lots of rows?

Comment: @Luuk I'm worried also that my query might take too long if i proceed on that process because it has too many rows if i split it.

Comment: The question has "Any suggestions on how I make this work?" Not "will this work in the future".  This other question is answered here: [Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) (and on other places on the internet)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. I have learned so many things today. Really Appreciated it.

Comment: Final comment, you can also create some data and test of it behave bad. An example of adding a longer record is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/2PiS10JN  (questions/comments about this should go in another question, not as follow-up here)

Comment: Got it. You might want to post your answer. Will gladly accept it as a correct answer. Thank you